# How can I fix this negative lookahead to make it work

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string for example as follows:

`ABCD17; ABC18; ABCEF19; XYZ19; ABCDE`

Within the MusicBee application, I'm attempting to use a Regex replace function to swap MATCHED items for blanks and thus transform the above string into

`ABCEF19; XYZ19`

i.e. ONLY retain the items ending in "19"

The elements can be any length and they may or may not end in a number.

The following expression correctly matches the items Ending in 19
`[^|;].*(?=19).{3}`

However, I obviously need the opposite of this (since the matched items are then replaced with empty strings) which is NOT (surprisingly to me)

`[^|;].*(?!19).{3}`

Comment: You want to remove all values that do not end on 19? Try `\b[A-Z]+(?:(?!19\b)\d+)?\b;?` https://regex101.com/r/11vXBR/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to keep items that end on 19, one option might be to use word boundaries `\b` and start matching 1+ uppercase chars A-Z.

Optionally match the digits at the end when it is not 19 using the negative lookahead `(?!19\b)`

```
\b[A-Z]+(?!19\b)\d*\b;?
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ uppercase chars A-Z (or use `[^\W\d]` to match word chars without a digit)
- `(?!19\b)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not 19
- `\d*` Match 0+ digits
- `\b;?` Word boundary and optionally match `;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfHblR/1)

Comment: Great - that works a treat.
Trying to understand HOW it works....
I totally get the \b at the start of the expression, but not the other two. I took out the word boundary after the 19 and it still works:

\b[A-Za-z]+(?:(?!19)\d+)?\b;?


What I can't understand is why the word boundary before the ";" is required? Although I can confirm that it doesn't work correctly without it!

Comment: @user194276 If you omit `(?!19\b)` then it would also not match 199 see [example](https://regex101.com/r/C34H3R/1). If you omit the last word boundary you could match for example ABCE in ABCEF19; as the digits and the `;` are optional. See [example](https://regex101.com/r/yh5DtZ/1)

Comment: Ah ok - the final word boundary stops the ABCD part of ABCD19 from being a match which would completely mess things up!

Thanks - that really helps!